# CSV library for PHP that supports adding / removing columns?

Tags: php, csv

Is there a PHP library for CSV manipulation that supports the insertion and deletion of columns?

I'm generating some large-ish CSVs and dataset size means that predicting the columns I'm going to need ahead of time isn't cutting it anymore- I'd like to be able to insert columns into the CSV (not necessarily at the far-right of the table) at runtime. Is there a library or function that can do this? `fputcsv()` and `fgetcsv()` aren't enough anymore.

Comment: have you tried mapping them to headers, then like an associative array the order wont matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/goodby/csv.

Or if by chance your end goal is to export to Excel and you don't need a more generic CSV export, check out PHPExcel (https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Header mapping  ( pseudo code )

```
 $header = fgetcsv( $f ); //get line1


 while( !feof($f) ){
      $data = array_combine( $header, fgetcsv($f) );
 }
```

You want like an associative array

```
   array( 'name' => 'someguy' ... );
```

Then the order no longer matters.   But if you mean adding a whole column to an existing file, then sadly no you have to rewrite the file.  I don't think you can just insert data at the right either because it will mess with the filepointer and byte order and various other complicated things.  At least in my experience I have had to pad the line with empty space, so that latter I can modify just the line and then trim to a set value, basically say that a line is always n number characters long etc.  But that might have been due to multiple process writing to the file, I cant recall off the top of my head.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do this on write. Up to now I've been analyzing all the (multidimensional) data, determining what columns I'm going to need, and then allocating columns before writing. I was hoping there might be a clever trick or class to do this that I'd missed in my research.

Comment: Have you looked at NoSQL databases, that is my next step for my csv needs.  You know store the data in Casandra or such and then generate the CSV when needed.  Flat files are just to ... restrictive.